# "confetti ascii" displayed in Windows

Tags: windows, graphics

A few apps on my Windows 11 system have started to display "confetti ascii", which is best described with a picture.  Here's the "Step 1" graphic in stackoverflow as rendered by Firefox.  But this also happens in *some* other apps, like slack:
[image]

This problem has persisted across multiple reboots, several software updates, and power-cycling my AOC / HDMI video monitor.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this, and a cure?

Update: I should have mentioned that live video shows up just fine, some text has no problems, but icons and some text seem to get "confetti'd".  So I don't think it's an HDMI cable issue, for example.

Comment: Update BIOS, Video Driver and if laptop, Chipset Driver. Reset and test.

Comment: For better or worse, the problem seems to have cleared up on its own.  Perhaps one of the many Windows updates fixed it?